# Aligning bootstrap dropdown with text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I created a Bootstrap dropdown using this code:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Ordered by
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="primary">Random</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Earliest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
    </ul>
    post.
</div>
```

But as you can see, the dropdown isn't aligned with the link:

[image: the problem]

How can I get it to align, and if possible, also display the white triangle on top pointing to the link?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JRcJr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/t75g5/

```
  <span>Ordered by<span>
    <div class="dropdown mydropdown" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="primary">Random <b class="caret"></b></span>

</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a href="#">Random</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Earliest</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Latest</a>

    </li>
</ul>post.</div>
```